# Resetting zone allocator with allocations still alive

Tags: swift

I'm receiving the following message in XCode 10.2.1 after my ViewController with a MKMapView gets de-initialized.

> [Memory] Resetting zone allocator with 24 allocations still alive

I'm using the following code in the ViewController to clean-up the MKMapView.  It doesn't seem to matter if I do this or remove the delegate in the ViewDidDisappear event.

```
deinit {
    self.mapView.delegate = nil
}
```

Is this indicating an actual memory leak or something else I need to fix?  It doesn't appear to be leaking memory after opening/closing the ViewController multiple times.

Comment: I'm seeing this too? Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not yet

Comment: For some reason I am only noticing the crash on iOS versions lower than 13.2.2.  So, the crash occurs on an iPad running 12.4.3.  Unfortunately it is an older device and cannot be updated to the latest iOS.  So I'm still a little stuck.  I can either have a memory leak, or a crash on the old model.  Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 8):

Calling `mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)` in the deinit fixed it for me. It was occurring only if there were clustered annotations and the map was being zoomed or panned right before deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was, I was manipulating MapView(addition of annotations, centering, displacement, zoom, etc.) and since I was computing Direction using  MKDirection which was happening in background thread, so Simply moving Map Manipulation on main thread fixed the issue for me.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Move all Zooming, adding Annotation related methods to Main Thread.
}
```