# SwiftUI MapKit [Memory] Resetting zone allocator with 24 allocations still alive

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I'm developing an Ipad app that contains a MapKit Map using SwiftUI and I get the following error message in the XCode console everytime when the view with the map disappears:

*[Memory] Resetting zone allocator with 24 allocations still alive*.

Thankful for any help on how to solve it. :)

### Related threads

First, before posting some code, let me say that there are a few threads related to this error. I've looked at this SO thread, [Resetting zone allocator with allocations still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061758/resetting-zone-allocator-with-allocations-still-alive), but it relates to UIKit and not to SwiftUI and either way I get the error message without adding annotations or zooming.

Another related thread here on SO is [SwiftUI - EnvironmentObject - Strange Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698873/swiftui-environmentobject-strange-memory-usage) but there the OP uses MKMapView instead of SwifUI's Map. Preferably, I'd like to use Map, but if nothing else MKMapView might be a way forward.

There is also some threads on the Apple developer forum, such as [this one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664762), but I've found no complete matches (in the linked thread, the OP only gets the error once, while it reoccurs for me every time the view with the map disappears).

### Minimal reproducible example

The error occurs *each time* the view button that removes the Map is pressed.

**View creating the error**

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
    @State private var showMap = true
    
    var body: some View {
        if showMap {
            VStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
                
                Button("Hide map") {
                    showMap = false
                }
                .font(.title)
            }
        } else {
            Button("Show map") {
                showMap = true
            }
            .font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

**Set-up view**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUIByExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting zone allocator with allocations still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061758/resetting-zone-allocator-with-allocations-still-alive)

Comment: I don't think so at least. The error remains even when I don't add any annotations nor do any zooming or panning.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including data that will cause the problem.

Comment: I already provided a reproducible example under the headline 'Code example'. I'll make it a little more minimal though.

Comment: I also added a set-up view for clarity. :)

Comment: I am not seeing the zone allocator error with the code you provided. Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15.2. That being said, from the linked question in the beginning, it seems to have something to do with not removing annotations before hiding the map. This would make sense as annotations are reused by the system if they disappear off screen. If you then make a whole new batch, you still have all of the old ones floating around. I would remove the annotations, or better yet, simply set the `.opacity()` of the map to 0 to hide it, rather than removing it from the hierarchy.

Comment: Interesting that you didn't get the error on iOS 15.2! I investigated a bit further and It turns out that the error shows up on my iPad wit iOS 15.1 but not and not on my iPhone (15.0.2). Where you using an iPhone?

Comment: Using ```.opacity()``` won't work however. The code I provided is just a minimal example and is not really related to the actual app. I will clarify this further in the question.

Comment: Simulator. Do you add annotations in your actual view?

Comment: I am not asking about the example, I am asking about your in use code. Since I am not seeing the error in your example & there are no annotations, this leads me to believe that it may be allocated annotations that are causing the issue. That being said, the view is obviously not happy about being removed and added to the view hierarchy multiple times. Why are you doing that instead of just hiding it?

Comment: Well, in the actual app, I do add annotations to the map, but since I'm not using any map annotations in the example I provided but still get the error, I assumed that the problem is not annotations.

Comment: In short, I don't do that in the actual app. The error shows up when user moves to other views or the app goes into the background.

Comment: When I tested the example I provided on the simulator instead of the actual hardware, I too run it without the error message!

Comment: That would have been helpful information.

Comment: Tested without issues on an actual device running 15.2. The problem is at your end, or this is not a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Much appreciated.

I still get the error on my device (an iPad mini 5g gen. with 15.2).

However, after more testing, I've noticed that the error sometimes does not appear in my minimal, reproducible example if I change between the views slowly. Seeing this, I managed to generate the error message using the simulator (iPad mini (6th gen)) by switching fast. On a similar note, I managed to avoid generating the error in the 'real' app by moving slowly, while moving fast generated the error (and moving extra fast even produced a new error).

Comment: The new, additional error: [TextureAtlas] TextureAtlasRegion: Texture atlas region should be inactive before deleting: Assertion with expression - _state == State::Inactive : Failed in file - /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1785.32.9.15.12/src/TextureAtlas2.cpp line - 584